# Скрип открывания div

Tags: jquery, html

Требуется:
При нажатии на ссылку открывает див с текстом в гулу экрана. Почитал уроки попробовал сделать, но конечного результата не добился вот прошу вашей помощи в доработке. В общем мне нужно еще дорабатывать:
1. Что бы менялся дизайн ссылки текст которой открыт.
2. Что бы 1 мог быть отрыть только 1 див. То есть при открытии второго первый автоматически закрывается.
Вот сам проект: http://jsfiddle.net/6gZGK/390/

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/vMYH8/2/

**Детали:**
**CSS:**

```
.testBlock{ width: 400px; height: 400px; outline: 1px solid red; }
.testList{ float: left; width: 150px;}
.testList ul{ list-style: none; }
.testList li a { text-decoration: none; color: #000; }
.testDesc{ float: right; width: 250px; height: 150px;}
.testDesc div{ height: 100%!important; border: 1px solid black; 
               background: #EAEAEA;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="testBlock">
    <div class="testList">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="testDesc">
        <div style="display: none;">Описание из ссылки 1</div>
        <div style="display: none;">Описание из ссылки 2</div>
        <div style="display: none;">Описание из ссылки 3</div>
        <div style="display: none;">Описание из ссылки 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS(jQuery):**

```
var lists = $(".testList li"), //объекты нашего списка
    descs = $(".testDesc div"), //блоки с описаниями

    //массив с цветами (будут использоваться по очереди)
    colors = new Array("#917E6A", "#D57363", "#B0DB7F", "#99CDDB");

$(".testList li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //что бы не срабатывали клики по ссылкам

    //перебираем все дивы и ссылки. Приводим к стандартному стилю.
    for(var i=0;i<descs.length;i++){
        descs[i].style.display = "none"; //скрываем все div-ы с описанием
        //делаем прозрачными ссылки
        lists[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
    isClick = lists.index(this); //индекс объекта по которому был произведен клик
    var its = descs[isClick]; //индекс объекта с описанием

    //Меняем цвет фона ссылки
    lists[isClick].getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
    .style.backgroundColor = colors[isClick];

    //задаем цвет фона с описанием относительно индекса, от 0 до n
    its.style.backgroundColor = colors[isClick];

    its.style.display = "block"; //делаем видимым блок с описанием

});
```

Comment: а можно что бы менялся цвет именно ссылки (ссылка 1 ссылка 2 и т.д.) а не блок и текст в блоке?

Comment: @kulgar, обновил свой ответ и ссылку на пример. С наступающим!)

Comment: @kulgar, Я еще раз обновил свой ответ, потому, что не верно Вас понял.

Comment: Добрый день и вас с наступающим, уже не хочу вас беспокоить, но что бы доделать и изучить на этом примере все же спрошу. Как сделать что бы менялся не цвет фона у кнопки ссылки, а именно сам цвет текста и только на белый ну или красный. Как в меню когда открытая страница отличается в меняю цветом или стилем. Как аналог в css A:active

Comment: @kulgar, Ван надо понять. **JS**, работает с разметкой страниц. То  есть ***.style.backgroundColor***, всё равно, что в **CSS** задать ***background-color*** – изменить фон объекта, а ***.style.color***, всё равно, что в **CSS** задать ***color*** – изменить цвет текста.  

Вот, сам пример:  
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/vMYH8/3/